# Best exception for an invalid generic type argument

Tags: c#, generics, exception

I'm currently writing some code for [UnconstrainedMelody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) which has generic methods to do with enums.

Now, I have a static class with a bunch of methods which are *only* meant to be used with "flags" enums. I can't add this as a constraint... so it's possible that they'll be called with other enum types too. In that case I'd like to throw an exception, but I'm not sure which one to throw.

Just to make this concrete, if I have something like this:

```
// Returns a value with all bits set by any values
public static T GetBitMask<T>() where T : struct, IEnumConstraint
{
    if (!IsFlags<T>()) // This method doesn't throw
    {
        throw new ???
    }
    // Normal work here
}
```

What's the best exception to throw? `ArgumentException` sounds logical, but it's a *type* argument rather than a normal argument, which could easily confuse things. Should I introduce my own `TypeArgumentException` class? Use `InvalidOperationException`? `NotSupportedException`? Anything else?

I'd *rather* not create my own exception for this unless it's clearly the right thing to do.

Comment: I stumbled across this today in writing a generic method where extra requirements are placed on the type being used that cannot be described with constraints.  I was surprised not to find an exception type already in the BCL.  But this exact dilemma was one I also faced a few days ago in the same project for a generic that'll only work with a Flags attribute.  Spooky!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`NotSupportedException` *sounds* like it plainly fits, but the documentation clearly states that it should be used for a different purpose. From the MSDN class remarks:

> There are methods that are not
>   supported in the base class, with the
>   expectation that these methods will be
>   implemented in the derived classes
>   instead. The derived class might
>   implement only a subset of the methods
>   from the base class, and throw
>   NotSupportedException for the
>   unsupported methods.

Of course, there's a way in which `NotSupportedException` is obviously good enough, especially given its common-sense meaning. Having said that, I'm not sure if it's just right.

Given the purpose of [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) ...

> There are various useful things that can be done with generic
>   methods/classes where there's a type constraint of "T : enum" or "T :
>   delegate" - but unfortunately, those are prohibited in C#.
>
> This utility library works around the prohibitions using ildasm/ilasm ...

... it seems like a new `Exception` might be in order despite the high burden of proof we  justly have to meet before creating custom `Exceptions`. Something like `InvalidTypeParameterException` might be useful throughout the library (or maybe not - this is surely an edge case, right?).

Will clients need to be able to distinguish this from BCL Exceptions?  When might a client accidentally call this using a vanilla `enum`? How would you answer the questions posed by the accepted answer to [What factors should be taken into consideration when writing a custom exception class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195834/what-factors-should-be-taken-into-consideration-when-writing-a-custom-exception-c/196211#196211)

Comment: In fact it's almost tempting to throw an internal-only exception in the first place, in the same way that Code Contracts does... I don't believe anyone *should* be catching it.

Comment: Too bad it can't just return null!

Comment: I'm going with TypeArgumentException.

Comment: Adding exceptions to the Framework may have a high "burden of proof", but defining custom exceptions shouldn't.  Things like `InvalidOperationException` are icky, because "Foo asks collection Bar to add something that already exists, so Bar throws IOE" and "Foo asks collection Bar to add something, so Bar calls Boz which throws IOE even though Bar isn't expecting it to" will both throw the same exception type; code which is expecting to catch the first won't be expecting the latter.  That having been said...

Comment: ...I would think the argument in favor of a Framework exception here is more compelling than for a custom exception.  The general nature of NSE is that when a reference to an object as a general type, and some but not all of the specific types of object to which the reference points will support an ability, attempting to use the ability on a specific type which doesn't support it should throw NSE.  I would consider a `Foo<T>` to be a "general type", and `Foo<Bar>` to be a "specific type" in that context, even though there's no "inheritance" relation between them.

Answer (score 28):

I would avoid NotSupportedException.  This exception is used in the framework where a method is not implemented and there is a property indicating that this type of operation is not supported.  It doesn't fit here

- Shameless self Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/12/12/notimplementedexception-vs-notsupportedexception.aspx

I think InvalidOperationException is the most appropriate exception you could throw here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about NSE. Would welcome input from your colleagues too, btw...

Comment: The point is, the functionality Jon needs has nothing similar in the BCL. The compiler is supposed to catch it. If you remove the "property" requirement from NotSupportedException, things you mentioned (like ReadOnly collection) are the closest thing to Jon's issue.

Comment: One point - I do have an IsFlags method (it has to be a method to be generic) which is *sort* of indicating that this type of operation is not supported... so in that sense NSE would be appropriate. i.e. the caller *can* check first.

Comment: @Jon: I think even if you don't have such a property **but** all members of your type inherently rely on the fact that `T` is an `enum` decorated with `Flags`, it would be valid to throw NSE.

Comment: In fact I *could* just go ahead and give an answer anyway, in all cases - but I don't like giving meaningless results when the developer should be made aware that they're trying to do bitwise operations on a non-bitwise enum...

Comment: @Jon, I can see that argument. It still feels a bit wrong to use it because I worry that a static methods constrained to a type don't have the ... cohesive ... feel that a single interface does. It's the cohesive nature of the interface that allows for the relationship between the property indicating support and the method.

Comment: Yup. InvalidOperationException still doesn't feel right either though. Trouble is, I really don't like creating my own exceptions if I can help it. Hmm. Might just do it anyway - at least for the moment.

Comment: @Jon: `StupidClrException` makes a fun name ;)

Comment: @Jon: Here's Brad Abrams's take on `NotImplementedException` and `NotSupportedException`: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/07/29/201354.aspx

Comment: My interpretation of the semantics of `NIE`/`NSE` is that throwing them shouldn't be contingent on the arguments used (whether standard or type arguments). A method is either implemented/supported or it isn't: If it doesn't throw `NIE`/`NSE` in *all* circumstances then it should *never* throw them.

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` means that it's invalid for the object's *current state.* But there is no state in which the same argument wouldn't cause the exception.

Answer (score 13):

Generic programming should not throw at runtime for invalid type parameters. It should not compile, you should have a compile time enforcement. I don't know what `IsFlag<T>()` contains, but perhaps you can turn this into a compile time enforcement, like trying to create a type that is only possible to create with 'flags'. Perhaps a `traits` class can help.

**Update**

If you *must* throw, I'd vote for InvalidOperationException. The reasoning is that generic types have *parameters* and errors related to (method) parameters are centered around the ArgumentException hierarchy. However, the [recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) on ArgumentException states that

> if the failure does not involve the
>   arguments themselves, then
>   InvalidOperationException should be
>   used.

There is at least one leap of faith in there, that *method* parameters recommendations are also to be applied to *generic* parameters, but there isn't anything better in the SystemException hierachy imho.

Comment: No, there's no way that this can be constrained at compile time. `IsFlag<T>` determines whether the enum has `[FlagsAttribute]` applied to it, and the CLR doesn't have constraints based on attributes. It would in a perfect world - or there'd be some other way to constrain it - but in this case it just doesn't work :(

Comment: (+1 for the general principle though - I'd love to be *able* to constrain it.)

Answer (score 10):

I would use NotSupportedException as that is what you are saying. Other enums than the specific ones are **not supported**. This would of course be stated more clearly in the exception message.

Comment: NotSupportedException is used for a very different purpose in the BCL.  It doesn't fit here.  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/12/12/notimplementedexception-vs-notsupportedexception.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, Microsoft uses `ArgumentException` for that, as demonstrated on example of [Expression.Lambda<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336566(v=vs.110).aspx), [Enum.TryParse<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261456(v=vs.110).aspx) in Exceptions section. I couldn't find any example indicating otherwise, either (despite searching local reference source for `TDelegate` and `TEnum`).

So, I think it's safe to assume that at least in Microsoft code it's a common practice to use `ArgumentException` for invalid generic type arguments aside from basic variable ones. Given that the exception description in [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't discriminate between those, it's not too much of a stretch, either.

Hopefully it decides the question things once and for all.

Comment: A single example in the framework isn't enough for me, no - given the number of places where I think MS has made poor choice in other cases :) I wouldn't derive `TypeArgumentException` from `ArgumentException`, simply because a type argument isn't a regular argument.

Comment: That's certainly more compelling in terms of "it's what MS does consistently". It doesn't make it any more compelling in terms of matching the documentation... and I know there are plenty of people in the C# team who care deeply about the difference between regular arguments and type arguments :) But thanks for the examples - they're very helpful.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Made an edit; now it includes 3 examples from different MS libraries, all with ArgumentException documented as the one thrown; so if it's a poor choice, at least it's a consistent poor choice. ;)
I guess Microsoft assumes that regular arguments and type arguments are both arguments; and personally, I think such assumption is quite reasonable. ^^'

Comment: Ah, nevermind, seems you noticed that already. Glad I could help. ^^

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on whether it's reasonable to treat them the same. They're certainly not the same when it comes to reflection, or language rules, etc... they're handled *very* differently.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Fair enough. For me, as a dev getting unhandled ArgumentException, it means "fix that argument!!1" and from my standpoint it makes little difference between replacing invalid regular or generic type argument; in both cases it's a bunch of keystrokes. I can understand the need for distinction, though, especially when the cause of exception is not to be corrected by dev, but handled by program.

Answer (score 8):

I'd go with `NotSupportedException`. While `ArgumentException` looks fine, it's really expected when an argument passed to a method is unacceptable. A type argument is a defining characteristic for the actual method you want to call, not a real "argument." `InvalidOperationException` should be thrown when the operation you're performing can be valid in some cases but for the particular situation, it's unacceptable.

`NotSupportedException` is thrown when an operation is inherently unsupported. For instance, when implementing an interface where a particular member doesn't make sense for a class. This looks like a similar situation.

Comment: Mmm. It still doesn't *quite* feel right, but I think it's going to be the closest thing to it.

Comment: Jon: it doesn't feel right because we naturally expect it to be catched by the compiler.

Comment: Yup. This is an odd kind of constraint that I'd like to be applied but can't :)

Answer (score 3):

Id go with NotSupportedExpcetion.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing a custom made exception should always be done in any case where it is questionable. A custom exception will always work, regardless of the API users needs. The developer could catch either exception type if he does not care, but if the developer needs special handling he will be SOL.

Comment: Also the developer should document all the exceptions thrown in the XML comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always wary of writing custom exceptions, purely on the grounds that they aren't always documented clearly and cause confusion if not named correctly.

In this case I would throw an ArgumentException for the flags check failure.  It's all down to preference really.  Some coding standards I've seen go as far as to define which types of exceptions should be thrown in scenarios like this.

If the user was trying to pass in something which wasn't an enum then I would throw an InvalidOperationException.

Edit:

The others raise an interesting point that this is not supported.  My only concern with a NotSupportedException is that generally those are the exceptions that get thrown when "dark matter" has been introduced to the system, or to put it another way, "This method must go into the system on this interface, but we won't turn it on until version 2.4"

I've also seen NotSupportedExceptions be thrown as a licensing exception "you're running the free version of this software, this function is not supported".

Edit 2:

Another possible one:

```
System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException
```

The exception thrown when using invalid arguments that are enumerators.

Comment: I'll have it constrained to be an enum (after some jiggery pokery) - it's only the flags I'm worried about.

Comment: I think those licensing guys should throw an instance of a `LicensingException` class inheriting from `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I agree Mehrdad,  Exceptions are unfortunately one of those areas where there is a lot of grey in the framework.  But I'm sure this is the same for lots of languages.  (not saying i'd go back to vb6's runtime error 13 hehe)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also vote for InvalidOperationException. I did an (incomplete) flowchart on [.NET exception throwing guidelines](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2009/01/24/net_exception_throwing_guidelines) based on [Framework Design Guidelines 2nd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) awhile back if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

How about inheriting from NotSupportedException. While I agree with @Mehrdad that it makes the most sense, I hear your point that it doesn't seem to fit perfectly. So inherit from NotSupportedException, and that way people coding against your API can still catch a NotSupportedException.