# Enum to dictionary and format each name

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I need  to convert enum to dictionary and after that format each name (value) of dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumToDictionary<TK>(Func<TK, string > func)
      {
        if (typeof(TK).BaseType != typeof(Enum))
              throw new InvalidCastException();


           return Enum.GetValues(
                typeof(TK))
                .Cast<Int32>()
                .ToDictionary(
                        currentItem => currentItem => Enum.GetName(typeof(TK), currentItem))
                 /*. func for each name */;
           }



      public enum Types {

            type1 = 0,
            type2 = 1,
            type3 = 2
         }


       public string FormatName(Types t) {
             switch (t) {
                         case Types.type1:
                                return "mytype1";

                         case Types.type2:
                              return "mytype2";

                         case Types.type3:
                              return "mytype3";

                           default:
                                return string.Empty;
                 }
           }
```

After that I need to do something like this:

```
var resultedAndFormatedDictionary = 
EnumToDictionary<Types>(/*delegate FormatName() for each element of dictionary() */);
```

How do I define and implement delegate (`Func<object, string > func`), which performs some action  for each value of dictionary?

UPDATE:
Correspoding result is

```
var a = EnumToDictionary<Types>(FormatName);

   //a[0] == "mytype1"
   //a[1] == "mytype2"
   //a[2] == "mytype3"
```

Comment: can you format this code little?

Comment: Can you also ask the question? Your whole post is just a statement so far. Whats the problem?

Comment: And please provide some sample input data and corresponding results

Comment: Don't you want a Func<TK, string> rather than Func<object, string>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your question you want to achieve to create a dictionary from an enum where the enum value as int is the key and some formatted name for it is the value, right?

Well, first the function you pass in should take `TK` as argument, shouldn't it?
Second, throwing a `InvalidCastException` seems a bit strange. An `InvalidOperationException` might be more appropriate (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412598/best-exception-for-an-invalid-generic-type-argument))
Third `ToDictionary` is already quite close:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumToDictionary<TK>(Func<TK, string> func)
{
     if (typeof(TK).BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Type must be enum");

     return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TK)).Cast<TK>().ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x), x => func(x));
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
public enum Types 
{
    type1 = 0,
    type2 = 1,
    type3 = 2
}

public string FormatName(Types t) 
{
    switch (t) 
    {
        case Types.type1:
            return "mytype1";

        case Types.type2:
            return "mytype2";

        case Types.type3:
             return "mytype3";

        default:
            return string.Empty;
     }
}

var resultedAndFormatedDictionary = EnumToDictionary<Types>(FormatName);
```

Comment: It doesn't compile  - 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context'