# Best practice for reporting an error in a type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there a particular best practice or other recommendation for reporting an invalid type parameter of a generic method in .NET?

(Specific example: I have a method with the signature

```
public static T GetRoles<T> (this WindowsIdentity id) where T: struct
```

I then do some reflection on T to ensure that it is both (a) an Enum, and (b) the right kind of Enum, since that's not a constraint I can use in the where clause.)

For most parameter errors I'd do the obvious thing and throw an ArgumentException with the appropriate parameter name and message, except since a type parameter isn't a regular argument, trying to throw a *new ArgumentException ("oops", "T")* makes the code analyzer complain that the parameter name, well, isn't one.  Which won't stop me if there isn't a better way to do it, of course, but if there is a specified or recommended practice in this area, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: (And even if it's not a formalized practice, I'm still interested in y'all's various solutions/reasoning, of course.)

Comment: In the specific case you mention, it might be worth investigating the [unconstrained melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library.

Comment: Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412598/best-exception-for-an-invalid-generic-type-argument)

Comment: @PaulPhillips - ooo, that's clever.  I've got some other cases to handle too, but not quite so many that running the assembly through a post-processor appeals, alas, but it's good to know that it exists.

Comment: @knaki02 - Thanks.  Guess things haven't changed since then, and I'll also be defining my own TypeArgumentException.

Answer (score 1):

Constraining to an enum can be adequately done by checking for the convertible interface:

```
where T : struct, IConvertible
```

This should save you some of the reflection work.